# regex - matching a string with the first occurrence case insensitive

Tags: php, regex

I need to modify a regular expression that matches a url for a redirect. The main part of it is this:

```
#^/webpages/ProdPage.aspx|^/default.asp#
```

That (i think) matches all the occurence that comes from `webpages/ProdPage.aspx` or `default.asp`. I need to modify it so that it will match `default.asp` *or* `Default.asp`. Maybe I should just add an `i` after the delimiter but I don't want the entire expression to be case insensitive.

thanx
Luke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `default.asp` to `[dD]efault.asp` to allow *just* the `d` to be lower or upper case.

Additionally, you might consider changing your `.` to `\.` as you want it to match a *literal* dot (ProdPage.aspx, default.asp). Otherwise, `.` will be interpreted in its regex sense meaning "any character except newline", so a page `webpages/ProdPageaaspx` would match (even though it's extremely unlikely...)